# Text align justify IE / Edge (inline-block)

Tags: internet-explorer, justify

i have simple, unsolved problemm with justifying inline blocks with IE and Edge browsers. Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari - works fine.

I know there are so many posts to solve it, but nothig helps for me!
What's my mistake for?

**JSFIDDLE:**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vpszLvLz/2/
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text-justify after">
  <a href="#" class="item">Left</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Center</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Right</a>
</div>

<div class="text-justify helper">
  <a href="#" class="item">Left</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Center</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Right</a>
  <div class="justify-helper"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
.text-justify ~ .text-justify {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.text-justify:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.item {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: coral;
  line-height: normal;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.justify-helper {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.text-justify.helper .item {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}
.text-justify.after:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-justify.helper .justify-helper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```